# Regex+Javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently practicing with Regex and I'm was thinking about making something like a calculator -> When I type "104+33" it should replace the text with "104 + 33 = 137". I already did a basic setup, so it's now just the regex stuff:

### What I tried

```
function regexStuff(string){
    return string.replace(/([\d+])\+([\d+])/g, '$1 + $2 = '+eval('$1+$2'));
}
```

**ERROR**: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $1 is not defined`

### Important

As I already mentioned: I am new to this regex stuff. It would be fantastic if you explain in in one or two sentences. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you evaling '$1*$2' ?

Comment: @dystroy Yea, noticed that a few seconds ago; My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can avoid using `eval`, do it : it's slow and dangerous.

Here you can do

```
return string.replace(/(\d+)\+(\d+)/g, function(a,b,c){ return a+'='+(+b+ +c) });
```

For example, if `string` is `"104+33"`, it returns `"104+33=137"`.

Note that I replaced `([\d+])` with `(\d+)` : your group matched a single digit, not a number.

As a final notice, be warned that you won't be able to go very far into making a calculator with just regexes. Sooner or later you'll have to use a parser to handle complex equations.

Comment: Your answer's good. +1. But please add that `+string` means `parseInt(string, 10)` so as not to confuse future visitors.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Or you could let your comment, in order to provide this necessary complementary information :)

Comment: @a duck In addition to dystroy's final notice, here's a [video](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=709991675708445) explaining how.

Comment: @ dystroy Ok, that's great :D

Comment: I don't know JS. Could you explain why the `//g` modifier is needed and what are `a,b,c` parameters and what does `a+'='+(+b+ +c)` do. Thanks. Never mind, just saw `parseInt(string, 10) `

Comment: The g flag is used to do more than one replacement. I suggest you to read this page about regexes in JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thanks for the link. I asked why `//g` only because he seems to be doing just 1 replacement.

Comment: +1 for lambda poetry. Noticed your tidy regex lately and thought I'd take a lazy sunday cruise through some old answers. :)